# How to default Media Player to open media files in C#

Tags: c#, media-player, default

I've Created a Media Player in C#(windows form applications).how to default this media player to open musics and movies when clicked on music anywhere.
just like KMPlayer and Windows Media Player.

Comment: You can't; this is based on a flag in the user's operating system for the "Default Application." If the user decides that your program is their first choice, then they have to the right click on the particular media file and choose it as the default option.

Comment: This is set up in the [registry](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/630ed1d9-73f1-4cc0-bc84-04f29cffc13b/what-registry-keys-are-responsible-for-file-extension-association?forum=netfxbcl)

Comment: when double clicked on music my media player can open that,this is what i want, kevin.